# Dynamically updated Xamarin.Forms ContentPage Content doesn't respond to user actions for iOS platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my **Xamarin.Forms** project which targets both **iOS** and **Android** platforms, I'm trying to change the `Content` of a `ContentPage` dynamically in the following way,

```
var currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
var oldContent = ((ContentPage)currentPage).Content;
var testLabel = new Label { Text = "Hello" };
var newContent = new Grid { Children = {oldContent, testLabel } };
((ContentPage)currentPage).Content = newContent;
```

This would display the `testLabel` on top of the `oldContent` successfully.

In **Android** platform, I can still interact with child elements (Buttons, ListView... etc) in the `oldContent` view. But in **iOS** the `oldContent` view child elements are not-interactive at this stage.

I have also made sure that the `testLabel` doesn't block the `oldContent`. This is how I made sure it doesn't block,

```
var currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
var oldContent = ((ContentPage)currentPage).Content;
var newContent = new Grid { Children = { oldContent } };
((ContentPage)currentPage).Content = newContent;
```

for this setup too, it's only for the **Android** platform that I can interact with `oldContent` child elements. But for **iOS** platform I cannot interact with `oldContent` child elements.

Also when I set the `oldContent` back as the `Content` of the `ContentPage`, then I can interact with the `oldContent` elements. In the same application flow.

`((ContentPage)currentPage).Content = oldContent;`

This allows me to interact with `oldContent` child elements for both **Android** and **iOS** platforms.

Have anyone got any idea how I can make the `oldContent` still interactive for **iOS** platform after dynamically changing the **Content** of the **ContentPage**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to achieve it,

I tried creating the `newContent` as an empty `Element`. Then replace the `Content` of the `ContentPage` with the `newContent`. Then add the relevant child elements into the `newContent` like below.

```
var newContent = new Grid ();
((ContentPage)currentPage).Content = newContent;
newContent.Children.Add(oldContent);
newContent.Children.Add(testLabel);
```

and bingo!!! it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note, you also HAVE to add the children AFTER you bind the new content - the problem persists otherwise.

This code still has the not-interactive elements in iOS:

```
var newContent = new Grid ();
newContent.Children.Add(oldContent);
newContent.Children.Add(testLabel);
((ContentPage)currentPage).Content = newContent;
```